# Как развернуть строку?

Tags: алгоритм, delphi, строки

Есть строка "4169BB8C". Как развернуть её в обратном порядке по 2 символа чтобы получилось "8CBB6941"?

```
var
i:integer;
str,s:string;
begin
str:='4169BB8C';
for i:=(length(str) div 2) downto 1 do begin
   s:= s+Copy(str, i+1, 2);
   end;
   print(str);
   print(s);    
end.
```

Что-то не очень получается.

Comment: Если отвечать прямо и просто, то через цикл. Но действительно нельзя ли по конкретнее?

Comment: Длина строки известна. Циклом проходим по символам строки с ее конца, и копируем каждые два символа в буфер. Затем из буфера формируем результирующую строку. Что не получается?

Comment: это у вас произвольная строка,  или шестнадцатиричная запись чего то? пара двух символов - байт. 4 пары - 4 байта, или двойное слово. вам все же надо строку инверсировать, или байты интеджера в обратном порядке вывести?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Гулять - так гулять:

```
var
  s: AnsiString;

  function BSwap(d: Dword): Dword;
  asm
    bswap eax
  end;

begin
  s:= '4169BB8C';
  Caption := BSwap(StrToInt('$'+s)).ToHexString;
```

C циклом и новой строкой:

```
 ns := '';
 for i:= length(s) div 2 downto 1 do
    ns:= ns + Copy(s, 2 * i - 1, 2);
 Caption := ns;
```

Comment: Ну могём)) В ассемблере не разбираюсь, поэтому сделал бы по-старинке -циклом `for i..downto..do`. Но Ваш вариант пободрее выглядит!

Comment: главное чтобы строка и правда была хексом не более 8 символов :)

Comment: @Dima Да конечно, учебная задача должна циклом решаться. Автор конкретную строку привёл длиной 8, содержащую только hex-цифры.

Comment: Вопрос не полный. Если подразумевается 4х байтное значение в HEX, то ответ вполне корректный.

Comment: дабы уменьшить количество asm строек можно сделать `function swap(d: dword):dword; asm bswap eax; end;`

Comment: и `IntToHex` вместо формата

Comment: @teran И тo верно, спасибо. С IntToHex катавасия в разных версиях Delphi. Можно ещё .ToHexString

Comment: Пробую так не получается
var
i:integer;
str,s:string;
begin
str:='4169BB8C';
for i:=(length(str) div 2) downto 1 do begin
   s:= s+Copy(str, i+1, 2);
   end;
   print(str);
   print(s);    
end.

Comment: @Mikhail, Ваш код полностью некорректен, но Вам дали ответ. Попробуйте использовать его. Если Вас все устроит в его работе, то нажмите на стрелочку (верхнюю!) и галочку под стрелочками, чтобы отблагодарить автора ответа.

Comment: @Mikhail Добавил код с циклом

Answer (score 0):

```
var
  i: integer;
  str,s: string;
begin
  str:='4169BB8C';

  for i:=length(str) downto 1 do
  begin
    i:=i-1;
    s:= s+Copy(str, i, 2);
  end;

  print(str);
  print(s);
end.
```

Comment: В коде ошибка: операции над счетчиком в теле цикла совершать нельзя. Компилятор не позволит.